# How to get private IP of VMSS using CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-vm-scale-set

I'm trying to automate few of our BAT script and for this our script need to know the private IP of each instances of VMSS(no public IP for instances).

Is there a way to query the private IP of all instances under a particular VMSS using azure cli. I tried few command of LB and VMSS but didn't find a solution yet.

```
az vmss show -g <rg> -n <vmss>
az vmss list-instances -g <rg> -n <vmss>
az vmss nic list-vm-nics -g <rg> --vmss-name <vmss> --ids <id>
az network lb address-pool list -g <rg> --lb-name <lb>
az vmss list-instance-connection-info -g <rg> -n <vmss>
```

Any help is highly appreciable and I'm not looking for powershell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the Azure CLI and bash command:

`az vmss nic list -g groupName --vmss-name ScaleSetName | grep -w "privateIpAddress"`

It can show all the private ips like this:

```
"privateIpAddress": "192.168.1.4",
"privateIpAddress": "192.168.1.5",
```

Comment: @ChrisBlom answer is awesome, to add to that the private IP param seems changed the the following: `az vmss nic list --resource-group ec-prod-rg --vmss-name ecprodwebvmss --query "[].ipConfigurations[].privateIpAddress`, you can find the first private IP address by changing both `[]` to `[0]`

Comment: I had to change the casing on `privateIPAddress` (capital `IP`) and then this worked great.